# why won't media query work on mobile and tablet

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

my media query works as per expected on my desktop however not in the mobile phone or the tablet.Please check out the live code here http://jsfiddle.net/E8cgT/

if the screen is bigger than 1024px it should be green my tablet screen is but the background stays yellow.

This also happens on my cell phone no matter what is stays yellow.

or read below

my html:

```
<html>

<head>
<title>Home Page</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<div id="master">
<header>
</header>

<nav>


Welcome to the home page from the sites directory 

<ul>
<li><a href="#">Meet Your Sensei</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Tour Our Dojo</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Our Martial Art Program</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Our Training Schedule</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Current Events</a></li>
<li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>

</div><!-- end of the master div tag -->

</body>
</html>
```

my css:

```
/* this will not work as we have below media to over ride */
body{ background-color: red;}


/* Low resolution for cell phones for 480 and below
*/
@media only screen and (max-width:480px)
{body{background-color: blue;}}

/* High resolution for screen between 1024 and above
*/
@media only screen and (min-width:1024px)
{body{background-color: green;}}

/* Medium resolution for screen between 481 and above
*/
@media only screen and (min-width:481px)
{body{background-color: yellow;}}
```

[SOLUTION]

1) The view port was something which I did not know about.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

2) I changed the priority of the screen after all is casing style sheets.

```
body {
background-color: red;
}

@media screen and (max-width:480px)
{body{background-color: blue;}}


/* Medium resolution for screen between 481 and above
*/
@media screen and (min-width:481px)
{body{background-color: yellow;}}


/* High resolution for screen between 1024 and above
*/
@media screen and (min-width:1024px)
{body{background-color: green;}}
```

Thank you all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if this helps you:
[Live view](http://fiddle.jshell.net/panchroma/4BVQm/show/)
[Edit view](http://jsfiddle.net/panchroma/4BVQm/)

I've made a few changes to your code;

Firstly you want to add

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

to the head of your page. This will stop smartphones and other devices from scaling the page.

In your media queries you use @media screen **only** and .... There's nothing wrong with using only in the selector, though it does have a specific use, to hide the style from older browsers. If this isn't intentional then you can omit it.
( The keyword ‘only’ can also be used to hide style sheets from older user agents.: [source](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/#media0)

I think you'll have an easier time targeting different size viewports if you use

```
@media screen and (min-width:Xpx) and (max-width:Ypx){  
....
}
```

as @Tdelang correctly pointed out.

Good luck!

Comment: Great help. It's the combination of the `<meta` and `@media screen and` that sorted it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Because of the cascade. You must set an upper limit for the middle breakpoint:

```
media only screen and (min-width:481px && max-width:1023px)
{
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using

```
@media all
```

or

```
 @media handheld, screen and (max-width:480px) { /* your css */ }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

http://jsfiddle.net/E8cgT/3/

CSS

```
/* this will not work as we have below media to over ride */
body {
    background-color: red;
}


 @media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px) {
body
    {
        background-color: blue;
    }

}

/* Low resolution for cell phones for 480 and below
*/
@media only screen and (max-width:480px) {
body {
    background-color: blue;
}
}



/* High resolution for screen between 1024 and above
*/
@media only screen and (max-width:1024px) {
body {
    background-color: green;
}
}

/* Medium resolution for screen between 481 and above
*/
@media only screen and (max-width:481px) {
body {
    background-color: yellow;
}
}
```

OR PLEASE USED THIS CSS FOR RESPONSIVE `MOBILE`,`TABLET`,`DESKTOP`

```
/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 321px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (max-width : 320px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : landscape) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : portrait) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Desktops and laptops ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 1224px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Large screens ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 1824px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPhone 4 ----------- */
@media
only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5),
only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5) {
/* Styles */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@media screen and (max-width:480px)
 {body{background-color: blue;}}

 /* High resolution for screen between 1024 and above
 */
@media screen and (min-width:1024px)
  {body{background-color: green;}}

/* Medium resolution for screen between 481 and above
*/
@media screen and (min-width:481px)
 {body{background-color: yellow;}}
```

use it this will work for me in mobile, ipad and also on window screen.